# ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined - Angular8

Tags: angular, tinymce

Using tinyMCE in my Angular 8 app and getting the error:

*ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined*

**component.ts**

```
declare const tinymce: any; // outside the class

ngAfterViewInit() { // inside the class
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'tinymce',
      height: 300,
      menubar: false,
      plugins: 'link lists paste image',
      toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor link image | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat'
    });
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<editor #tinymce id="tinymce" apiKey="mykeyishere" formControlName="article"></editor>
```

I'm trying to call init() on tinymce from the component rather than the template because I can't do this (from the [official docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/local-upload/#)) in the template:

```
/* without images_upload_url set, Upload tab won't show up*/
  images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',

  /* we override default upload handler to simulate successful upload*/
  images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      /* no matter what you upload, we will turn it into TinyMCE logo :)*/
      success('http://moxiecode.cachefly.net/tinymce/v9/images/logo.png');
    }, 2000);
  }
```

I need to define custom upload image handler in my component but the docs for TinyMCE Angular only cover the use case where init is called from the template so there's no solution in the docs when it comes to handling image upload.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I strugled with the same problem, with Angular 10.
I fixed it by adding this script inside the head of index.html :

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

I found the src link here :

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tinymce.

For info, I am using IntelliJ ultimate. After having declared the script, IntelliJ proposed me to download the script src library.
I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: I already have this in the head section, still getting the error